# JPA merge update bi-directional

Tags: jpa

Update bidirectional mapping using jpa merge.

The relationship between manager to project is 1:M.

How to save/update both entity same time using JPA merge. It is causing child data to delete if the child is not added back.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or what the problem you are encountering is.

Comment: Still not following.  If customer has 3 products, it should have a reference to all 3 products, so I don't see why you are calling customer.getlist.add for product 1.  If it is bidirectional, and you've added a product->Customer reference, then you should also have added customer->Product references as well.  As the question author, you should be able to update your question to make rather than just adding clarification in the comments.  Try describing the problem you are seeing and what you are doing if you want an explanation as to why its happening

Comment: I found the answer if we are using JPA merge we need to add all child entity back again in order for them to persist unless untouched child record(s) could be deleted.